# Get each element get height and apply it as margin-top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 blocks of images with text on top of them. Here is how one of the 3 looks like.

```
<div class="lp">
    <h2 class="align-vert">
        This is my title
    </h2>
</div>
```

I want to get the title `height();` in jQuery and apply it to the `aligh-v`. I tried the following jQuery code but it doesn't work.

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('.js-vert'), function() {
    jQuery(this).css({
        "margin-top": '"' + jQuery('.js-vert').height() + '"'
    });
});
```

Comment: What is `.js-vert` ? It doesn't seems included in your DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because you need to use the `this` reference within the `each()` method to refer to the current element. As it stands, your code is calling `height()` the entire set of elements which means only the height of the first element is returned. Your syntax of string concatenation is also a little off. Try this:

```
$('.js-vert').each(function() {
    $(this).css("margin-top", $(this).height());
});
```

Also note that this can be made more succinct by removing the `each()` loop entirely and passing a function to the `css()` method which returns the value needed:

```
$('.js-vert').css('margin-top', function() {
    return $(this).height();
});
```

Comment: Didn't know you could pass a function to that method. Awesome! +1